# sqlite3, best way to retrieve row elements by index?

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

I am using sqlite3, and table has 25 entries. I execute:

```
select * from mytable;
```

and using sqlite3_step to retrieve each row, and to get the column,

```
sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 5);
```

I am using the index value as a hard coded integer. The problem i m facing is if there are 
any new table entry added [ie prefixed] , then i need to change the index also.

It is not a problem, but it is a maintainability issue. Is there any best approach/pattern to achieve differently? Kindly advice.

Comment: Do you mean, when a new *column* is added to the table?

Answer (score 0):

Ah...

Something like this:

```
enum {

 COLUMN_NAME,

 COLUMN_AGE,

 COLUMN_ID,

 COLUMN_END

};



char *arr[COLUMN_END];

for (i=0; i<COLUMN_END; i++)
    arr[i] = malloc(50);

strcpy (arr[COLUMN_NAME] = "name");

strcpy (arr[COLUMN_AGE] = "age");
```

Preparing SQL Statement:

```
sqlite_mprintf (" insert into mytable ('%s', '%s' , '%s') values ('%s',%d,%d)", arr[COLUMN_NAME], arr[COLUMN_AGE], arr[COLUMN_ID], "whoami", 10, 2323)");
```

While retrieving:

sqlite3_stmt_text (stmt, COLUMN_NAME);

will this be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `select *` use `select col1, col2, col3...`

This way order and position of columns of the result is the same no matter what happens to the table (as long as all these columns exist...)